# Problem with Users list filtering

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, user-list

On any of the trilogy sites, if I go to the `Users` tab and type a single character, the "Oops something bad happens" image for that site shows up for about a second where the users list was, and then the whole window goes blank. This is new behavior, at some point in the past it definitely worked, and it still works as long as I type several characters. It happens on both Firefox 3.6.3 and Chromium, both on Linux

Comment: Probably related to the fix applied for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54707/searching-users-resets-after-some-time

Comment: Also, repro in XP + FF 3.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix confirmed.

<sub><sup>Posting an answer so this question doesn't keep getting bumped.</sup></sub>